# Remove required in the field Contact Form 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7, required-field

is it possible to remove this attribute or class from the field placed in the form?

I have some fields as required, but for a strange reason, it marks all the fields as required

```
<label>Name:
[text* your-name] </label>

<label>Phone: 
[tel* telefono]</label>

<label>Account (format: xxxx-xxxx-xx)
[text* presupuestaria]</label>

<p>How many pages does your document have?
[text totalpaginas]</p>

<p>What is the Number of Copies do you need?::
[text canticopia]</p>

<p>It is confidential?[select confiden id:confidenselect "No" "Si"]</p>
[group group-999 clear_on_hide inline]
<div id="confident">Data of the person who will withdraw the copies
<p>Name:[text sinombrefoto]</p>
<p>Email: [text siemailfoto]</p>
</div>
[/group]
<p style=”float:right”>
[submit “Submit”]
</p>
```

I try to send the form but it tells me that I have empty fields and these, as they are seen in the code, are not as required

```
<input type="text" name="totalpaginas" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false" required="">
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the validation from one field you need to add a filter:

```
function so73691953_validation_filter($result,$tag){
        $name = $tag->name;
        $exception_fields = array(
            'totalpaginas'
        );
        if (in_array($name, $exception_fields)) {
            return $result;
        }
        if($_POST[$name] == '') {
            $result->invalidate( $tag, "This field cannot be empty.");
        }
    return $result;
}   
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text*', 'so73691953_validation_filter', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text', 'so73691953_validation_filter', 10, 2 );
```

This filter validates that all fields are non-empty, except the names of the inputs defined in the $exception_fields array